# Live video stream from C application to php

Tags: php, javascript, c

I have an application written in C that captures an image via webcam,does some processing on it,and then sends the resulting image through socket to a client application,also written in C,in another computer.
I want to do something similar but using a webpage as the client.Is there a way to do this using php or javascript?

Comment: Yes there is a way. Do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could obviously use an intermediary server that accepts the captured images and then serves them out via http requests.  (Think flickr.com or photobucket.com)  You don't have to write that server's code in PHP, you can use any server-side language.

As it so happens, modern standards are actually pushing a thing called "Websockets":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

But if you're only serving a single image with processing, it sounds like doing a websocket approach would be overkill.  (You say "video", but then speak about sending "an image...")

Most people historically did video on the web using flash clients, which have sockets available.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is you want the client to get the results using a browser. You don't need PHP, Simple HTML will do. You can implement a very simple http server in your c program (the one capturing images) that serves requests for files. [Here's a sample in C](http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/c/webserv.php). Captured images will be saved on the local disk and served upon request. Alternatively, they can be captured once a request arrives and served to the requesting client. Of course, you can also have a java script on the client side to refresh if you need to get frequent images.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to do this entirely using PHP and JavaScript, as PHP runs on the server side (and thus has no access to the client's camera), and most browsers* do not currently expose webcams via JavaScript.

Flash files do have access to the webcam, though. Flash also has network access, so it may make the most sense to write both the video capture and network transmission components in it.

*: The odd exception being Opera. But that's not really widely used enough to make it a significant exception.